# Can't upload aab/apk to play store with Fastlane

Tags: android, google-play, fastlane

I have an android application that I want to upload to the play store using Fastlane. When I use command to upload,`fastlane internal`, I get the following error:

```
28 $ fastlane internal
29 [19:55:02]: Get started using a Gemfile for fastlane https://docs.fastlane.tools/getting-started/ios/setup/#use-a-gemfile
30 [19:55:02]: Sending anonymous analytics information
31 [19:55:02]: Learn more at https://docs.fastlane.tools/#metrics
32 [19:55:02]: No personal or sensitive data is sent.
33 [19:55:02]: You can disable this by adding `opt_out_usage` at the top of your Fastfile
34 [19:55:02]: ---------------------------
35 [19:55:02]: --- Step: opt_out_usage ---
36 [19:55:02]: ---------------------------
37 [19:55:02]: Disabled upload of used actions
38 [19:55:02]: ------------------------------
39 [19:55:02]: --- Step: default_platform ---
40 [19:55:02]: ------------------------------
41 [19:55:02]: Driving the lane 'android internal' 
42 [19:55:02]: ----------------------------------
43 [19:55:02]: --- Step: upload_to_play_store ---
44 [19:55:02]: ----------------------------------
45 +-------------------------+-----------------------------------------------+
46 |                       Summary for supply 2.135.2                        |
47 +-------------------------+-----------------------------------------------+
48 | track                   | internal                                      |
49 | apk                     | app/build/outputs/apk/release/app-release.apk |
50 | package_name            | com.myapp.andriod                       |
51 | release_status          | completed                                     |
52 | json_key                | /play-store-config.json                       |
53 | skip_upload_apk         | false                                         |
54 | skip_upload_aab         | false                                         |
55 | skip_upload_metadata    | false                                         |
56 | skip_upload_changelogs  | false                                         |
57 | skip_upload_images      | false                                         |
58 | skip_upload_screenshots | false                                         |
59 | validate_only           | false                                         |
60 | check_superseded_tracks | false                                         |
61 | timeout                 | 300                                           |
62 | deactivate_on_promote   | true                                          |
63 +-------------------------+-----------------------------------------------+
64 +------------------+------------------+
65 |            Lane Context             |
66 +------------------+------------------+
67 | DEFAULT_PLATFORM | android          |
68 | PLATFORM_NAME    | android          |
69 | LANE_NAME        | android internal |
70 +------------------+------------------+
71 [19:55:02]: Google Api Error: applicationNotFound: No application was found for the given package name. - No application was found for the given package name.
72 +------+----------------------+-------------+
73 |             fastlane summary              |
74 +------+----------------------+-------------+
75 | Step | Action               | Time (in s) |
76 +------+----------------------+-------------+
77 | 1    | opt_out_usage        | 0           |
78 | 2    | default_platform     | 0           |
79 |    | upload_to_play_store | 0           |
80 +------+----------------------+-------------+
81 [19:55:02]: fastlane finished with errors
82 [!] Google Api Error: applicationNotFound: No application was found for the given package name. - No application was found for the given package name.
86 ERROR: Job failed: command terminated with exit code 1
```

The general fix for this issue is to create the project in the Play Console and then manually uploading the APK. I have created the application in the Play Console by manually uploading an APK but I am still getting the same error.

Comment: Are you sure your app's package name really is "com.myapp.andriod"?

Comment: @JulienArzul it's not. I just insert "com.myapp.andriod" to not reveal any information.

Comment: Right ok, makes sense, just wanted to make sure! Other question: have you published the app on the Play Store console? (I'm not sure you have to but that might help)

Comment: Having the same issue as yours

Comment: @JulienArzul yes it was published. still got the same errors.

Comment: @Smakosh For publishing to the play store, I switched over to - https://github.com/Triple-T/gradle-play-publisher